# Converting factor class to numeric in a zero indexed fashion in r

Tags: r, dataframe, type-conversion

When converting a factor class column in a dataframe to numeric, the individual levels in a column are converted to integer, based on alphabetical order as I understand it. Is there a way to convert them to integers starting from 0. Below is an example code:

```r
target <- as.factor(c("<50", ">=50",">=50",">=50","<50"))
feat1 <- as.numeric(c(1,2,3,4,5))
feat2 <- as.factor(c("cat", "dog", "monkey","seal", "monkey"))

dat <- data.frame(feat1, feat2, target)

dat

for(col in names(dat)){
  if(class(dat[[col]]) == "factor"){
    dat[[col]] <- as.numeric(dat[[col]])
  }
}
```

Comment: `as.numeric(dat$feat2) - 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.factor), ~ as.numeric(.) - 1))
```

Or in base `R`:

```
dat[] <- lapply(dat, function(x) if (is.factor(x)) as.numeric(x) - 1 else x)
```

**Output**

```
  feat1 feat2 target
1     1     0      0
2     2     1      1
3     3     2      1
4     4     3      1
5     5     2      0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- names(sapply(dat, is.factor))
setDT(dat)[, (nm1) := lapply(.SD, as.numeric) - 1, .SDcols = nm1]
```